# Setting limitless timeout on Doctrine2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I set timeout to no limit on Doctrine2 for MongoDb used in Symfony2.3? Tried to set the limit and the query after 30 seconds timesout but the 'raw' query works fine on Mongodb CLI which takes about 90 seconds (or more) to complete.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('BaseLog')
->hydrate(true)
 ->field('template_id')->Equals($templateId);
...
return $qb->getQuery(array('timeout' => -1))->execute();
```

Comment: you can try disabling the php timeout with `set_time_limit(0)`  before executing your code.

Comment: set_time_limit(0) doesn't seem to have a global effect when used in Symfony task class that also includes other stacks of classes up to Doctrine.

Comment: where do you execute your code? In a controller or in a command?

Comment: I run the Symfony task in the command line.

Comment: So which component rise a timeout? Do you have a stracktrace? Usually i haven't any issue about long task running via command...

Comment: It's Doctrine and the error is like: 
"Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds - #0 ...vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Cursor.php(409): MongoCursor->next()"

Comment: Hi! Have you solve your issue?

Comment: Hi @Matteo. No. I ended up leaving out Doctrine and worked directly on Mongo PHP extension which worked

        $connection = $this->mongoConnection;
        $collection = $connection->MyDb->MyCollect;
        ....
        $cursor  = $collection->find($query);
        $cursor->timeout(-1);
        $numDocs = $cursor->count();

Answer (score 1):

Seems the timeout of the MongoDB cursor Object (a timeout can be changed as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php)).

With the DoctrineMongoDBBundle you can modify the `timeout` configuration key, as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html#full-default-configuration). Change the config.yml as example, as follow:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options:
              timeout: 240  # <-- increase the default timeout

    default_database: hello_%kernel.environment%
    document_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                AcmeDemoBundle: ~
            filters:
                filter-name:
                    class: Class\Example\Filter\ODM\ExampleFilter
                    enabled: true
            metadata_cache_driver: array # array, apc, xcache, memcache
```

Hope this help